# Java NIO Search file in a directory

Tags: java, file, nio, glob

I want to search a file(without knowing the full name) in a specific directory using Java NIO and glob.

```
public static void match(String glob, String location) throws IOException {

        final PathMatcher pathMatcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher(
                glob);

        Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(location), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path,
                    BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                if (pathMatcher.matches(path)) {
                    System.out.println(path);
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    }
```

Reading some tutorial I did this. I just want to return string if I find(first) file with given glob String.

```
if (pathMatcher.matches(path)) {
    return path.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two things to be changed:

To "*find(first) file with given glob String*" you need to finish walking the tree if you encounter the file, thus if a match is given. And you need to store the matching path as result. The result of `Files.walkFileTree` itself is the "the starting file" ([JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.FileVisitor))). That's a `Path` pointing to the `location`.

```
public static String match(String glob, String location) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    PathMatcher pathMatcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher(glob);
    Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(location), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            if (pathMatcher.matches(path)) {
                result.append(path.toString());
                return FileVisitResult.TERMINATE;
            }
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });

    return result.toString();
}
```

If there is no match then the resulting `String` is empty.

EDIT:
Using `Files.walk` we can implement the search with less code still using a glob expression based matcher:

```
public static Optional<Path> match(String glob, String location) throws IOException {
    PathMatcher pathMatcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher(glob);
    return Files.walk(Paths.get(location)).filter(pathMatcher::matches).findFirst();
}
```

The `Optional` as result shows that there may be no match.

Comment: Use a nullable `String` instead of a `StringBuilder`. That's less overhead and still accurte

Comment: How should this work? The `String` variable wouldn't be effective final anymore.

Comment: You're right. Maybe put an `AtomicReference` or use a `var wrapper = new Object() { Path reference; }` if you use Java 11+.

Comment: Do you think this would be more readable? Is this because you prefer return `null` instead of an empty `String` if no result is found?

Comment: Or `try(Stream<Path> stream = Files.find​(Paths.get(location), Integer.MAX_VALUE, (path,attr) -> pathMatcher.matches​(path))) { return stream.findFirst().orElse(null); }`

Answer (score 4):

Based on your own code. Just stop traversing once found some match

```
public class Main {

    private static Path found = "nothing"; // First file found

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String glob = "glob:**.{java}"; //pattern to look for
        String location = "D:\\"; //where to search
        match(location, glob);
        System.out.println("Found: " + found);
    }

    public static void match(String location, String glob) throws IOException {

        final PathMatcher pathMatcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher(glob);

        Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(location), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                if (pathMatcher.matches(path)) {
                    found = path; // Match found, stop traversal
                    return FileVisitResult.TERMINATE;
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Or you can populate collection saving all the files matching the pattern

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect `{prop*}` to do but I'd avoid mixing the `{alt1,alt2,...}` syntax with wildcards. I just tested it under `bash` and the inner wildcard isn't expanded but rather understood as a literal `*`. I haven't tested with Java so it might just work, but you'd be at least sure to confuse people familiar with linux

Comment: @Aaron used it to look for properties in Windows. Not sure about bash but you are right, better to edit to avoid potential troubles

Comment: Also, the OP wants to *return* a string. Could you put the `found` in the `match` method and return it at the end of the method, making the `void`-returning method a `Path`-returning method?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this example could help you further, but it seems like you would need your own custom file visitor. Here is an alternative solution:

```
package com.jesperancinha.files;

import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.PathMatcher;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

public class GlobFileVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {
    private final PathMatcher pathMatcher;

    private Path path;

    public GlobFileVisitor(String glob) {
        this.pathMatcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher(glob);
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path, BasicFileAttributes attrs) {
        if (pathMatcher.matches(path)) {
            this.path = path;
            return FileVisitResult.TERMINATE;
        }
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    public Path getFoundPath() {
        return path;
    }
}
```

And this is another possibility for your running example:

```
package com.jesperancinha.files;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class FileFinder {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String glob = "glob:**.{java}";
        String location = "/Users/joao/dev/src/jesperancinha";
        Path found = match(location, glob);
        System.out.println("Found: " + found);
    }

    public static Path match(String location, String glob) throws IOException {
        GlobFileVisitor globFileVisitor = new GlobFileVisitor(glob);
        Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(location), globFileVisitor);
        return globFileVisitor.getFoundPath();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These answers will all work, but the intended way to search for files with NIO is `Files.Find` with a `BiPreicate<Path,BasicFileAttributes>`.

```
PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:*.txt");
Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(
        Paths.get("/dirToSearch"),
        1, // Search depth of 1 in our case, set to >1 or -1 to explore subfolders
        (path, basicFileAttributes) ->  matcher.matches(path)
);
// The stream is lazily populated
Path firstMatch = stream.findFirst().get();
```